# Missing parameter in sql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, odbc

here is my code for sql operation..

```
$conn= get_db_connection();
    var_dump($data);
    $PickupDate     =   date('m/d/Y', strtotime($data[17]));
    $OrderNum       =    $data[4];
    $TrackingID     =   $data[15];
echo $sql_1 =   'UPDATE Tracking SET Tracking.PickupDate = "'.$PickupDate.'", Tracking.Carrier = "USPS", Tracking.EmailSent = "-1", Tracking.Notes = "Inserted by TIA", Tracking.TrackingID = "'.$TrackingID.'", Tracking.External= "1" WHERE Tracking.OrderNum= "'.$OrderNum.'"';
$rs1=odbc_exec($conn,$sql_1);
```

echoing the query results in

> UPDATE Tracking SET Tracking.PickupDate = "10/03/2013",
>   Tracking.Carrier = "USPS", Tracking.EmailSent = "-1", Tracking.Notes =
>   "Inserted by TIA", Tracking.TrackingID = "9400110200881918988535",
>   Tracking.External= "1" WHERE Tracking.OrderNum= "59836"

if I paste this query directly to access ( this echoed version) it works..
but when I run it via my odbc connection...the error is...

**Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 7., SQL state 07001 in SQLExecDirect in D:\wamp1\www\ftp\ftp_functions.php on line 94**

line 94 is `$rs1=odbc_exec($conn,$sql_1);`

so, I can see, every parameter is present is my query, still getting the error,

trying to troubleshoot it for hours, but no success,

can some body help me??
thanks in advance

ps:
pickupdate, ordernum, trackingID, all of these are TEXT ( working with stone edge :( no control over data types, though I belive they should be of date and int type)

Comment: Somebody may see your issue immediately, but I would try rebuilding the query one step at a time. Only set 1 field, see if that works. Then set 2, see if that works. That way you can see which field in your PHP is "missing".

Comment: not a bad idea at all, going to try it right now..

Comment: not working even if I try it with only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
$sql_1  =   "UPDATE Tracking
 SET PickupDate='$PickupDate', TrackingID = $TrackingID, 
  Tracking.Carrier = 'USPS', Tracking.EmailSent = '-1', Tracking.Notes = 'Inserted by TIA', Tracking.External= '1'
 where OrderNum='$OrderNum'";
```

seems like odbc and ms-access was creating issues with qoutes